# Pressing enter key creates a blank span in tinymce editor

Tags: tinymce

I am using tinyMCE editor in one of my project. When I press enter key inside the equation box,I want to reload the contents of the editor.It works well now but the problem I am facing here is an empty span with class AM that is automatically created on pressing enter key.The tinymce function for reloading the contents is :

```
tinyMCE.execCommand("mceRepaint");
```

I have made a javascript functin for this which is given below :

```
function loadlistener() {
//console.log('load');
$("#elm1_ifr").contents().keydown(function (event) {
    //console.log('key');
    var code = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    //console.log(code);
    if (code == 13 && amedit) {

        tinyMCE.execCommand("mceRepaint");
        tinyMCE.activeEditor.focus();

    }
});
var p_parent = $("#elm1_ifr").contents().find("p");
setInterval(function () {
    if (p_parent.find('span').length && p_parent.find('span')) {

        amedit = true;
    } else {
        amedit = false;
    }
}, 200)
```

};
So my question is how to prevent the creation of this empty span when enter key is pressed.
You can check it live [Here](http://beyondthelogix.com/demos/editordemo/demo.html)

Pleas inspect the html so you can understand my question more clearly.